# org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'actionTypeManager': Injection of autowired dependencies failed

Tags: spring

Please find the full stacktrace

```
2011-09-14 15:45:47 ContextLoader [ERROR] Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'actionTypeManager': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.spri
ngframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.abc.exp.abc..abc.security.actiontype.ActionTypeInterface com.abc.exp.abc..abc.secur
ity.actiontype.ActionTypeManager.aInterface; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'JPAActionType': Injection o
f persistence dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in clas
s path resource [beans.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.apache.log4j.Logger.trace(Ljava/lang/String;)V
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:285)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1074)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:580)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:895)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:425)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:276)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:197)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:47)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:3972)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4467)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:791)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:771)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:546)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:905)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWARs(HostConfig.java:740)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:500)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1277)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:321)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1053)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:785)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:443)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:519)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:710)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:581)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.abc.exp.abc..abc.security.actiontype.ActionTypeInterface com.abc.e
xp.abc..abc.security.actiontype.ActionTypeManager.aInterface; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'JPAActio
nType': Injection of persistence dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFacto
ry' defined in class path resource [beans.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.apache.log4j.Logger.trace(Ljava/lang/String
;)V
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:502)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:84)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:282)
        ... 37 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'JPAActionType': Injection of persistence dependencies failed; nested exception is
 org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [beans.xml]: Invocation of init method
 failed; nested exception is java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.apache.log4j.Logger.trace(Ljava/lang/String;)V
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:341)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1074)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:844)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:786)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:703)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:474)
        ... 39 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [beans.xml]: Invocation of i
nit method failed; nested exception is java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.apache.log4j.Logger.trace(Ljava/lang/String;)V
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1420)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.findDefaultEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:529)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.findEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:495)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$PersistenceElement.resolveEntityManager(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:656)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$PersistenceElement.getResourceToInject(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:629)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata$InjectedElement.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:147)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:84)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:338)
        ... 50 more
Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.apache.log4j.Logger.trace(Ljava/lang/String;)V
        at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.PropertyBinder.make(PropertyBinder.java:184)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.bindId(AnnotationBinder.java:1911)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.processElementAnnotations(AnnotationBinder.java:1279)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.bindClass(AnnotationBinder.java:754)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.processArtifactsOfType(AnnotationConfiguration.java:546)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.secondPassCompile(AnnotationConfiguration.java:291)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildMappings(Configuration.java:1148)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildMappings(Ejb3Configuration.java:1226)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.EventListenerConfigurator.configure(EventListenerConfigurator.java:173)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.configure(Ejb3Configuration.java:854)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.configure(Ejb3Configuration.java:425)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:131)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:225)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:308)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1477)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1417)
        ... 63 more
14 Sep, 2011 3:45:47 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SEVERE: Error listenerStart
14 Sep, 2011 3:45:47 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SEVERE: Context [/abc.] startup failed due to previous errors
14 Sep, 2011 3:45:47 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesJdbc
SEVERE: A web application registered the JBDC driver [org.h2.Driver] but failed to unregister it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has
 been forcibly unregistered.
14 Sep, 2011 3:45:47 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory docs
14 Sep, 2011 3:45:47 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory ROOT
14 Sep, 2011 3:45:47 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol start
INFO: Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
14 Sep, 2011 3:45:47 PM org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket init
INFO: JK: ajp13 listening on /0.0.0.0:8009
14 Sep, 2011 3:45:47 PM org.apache.jk.server.JkMain start
INFO: Jk running ID=0 time=0/18  config=null
14 Sep, 2011 3:45:47 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 9212 ms
```

Answer (score 0):

spring is complaining that there was a fault in bean creation (which is obvious), the root cause can be found once you paste the fill stack trace...
from what you've pasted so far it looks like the trouble is with `entityManagerFactory` bean.
Please review the code to see if you've missed setting any property or are passing an incorrect reference to a property.

`Could not autowire field: private com.abc.exp.abc..abc.security.actiontype.ActionTypeInterface com.abc.exp.abc..abc.secur
ity.actiontype.ActionTypeManager.aInterface`

please ensure that there is something which can be injected into the field under question or remove the `@Autowired` annotation from the field.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a possible explanation:

```
Could not autowire field: private com.abc.security.actiontype.ActionTypeInterface
```

What good is a private interface?  Is that yours?